# LiveServerTestCase - settings.Database is improperly configured

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, selenium, testing

I'm trying to set up a LiveServerTestCase.

For this I'm creating a User within my Testclass with

```
class ExampleTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    user = User.objects.create_superuser('Testuser','test@user.com','1234')
    user.save()
.
.
.(rest of the test)
```

without this line the server and test starts but obviously it can't login because there is no User created before.

But with this line I'm getting a

```
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES
 is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value.
```

error.

Do I need to set up the Server in settings.py for LiveServerTestCase, and in case yes, with which values or where do I find them?

UPDATE:

I'm running this test with

```
python manage.py test
```

so it sets up a database itself which I don't have to define in the settings.py, or am I wrong.

UPDATE2:

I already defined a 'production' database (before I even asked the question), it looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
 'default': {
     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
     'HOST': 'localhost',  # 10.1.2.41
     'NAME': 'pim_testdatabase',
     'USER': 'postgres',
     'PASSWORD': '1234',
     'PORT': '5432',
     'HAS_HSTORE': True,
     'TEST':{
             'NAME': 'test_pim_testdatabase'
      },
  },
}
```

Still the exception appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating the user in the class definition. This runs when the test class is loaded, before the database has been created.

```
class ExampleTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    user = User.objects.create_superuser('Testuser','test@user.com','1234')
    user.save()  # This save isn't required -- it has been saved already
```

You can fix the problem by moving the user creation into an individual test. Then the user will be created when the test method runs, after the database has been created.

```
class ExampleTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def test_user(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_superuser('Testuser','test@user.com','1234')
        ...
```

Django 1.8 has a [`setUpTestData`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData) method where you can set up initial data once for the entire test case. This is quicker, and less repetitive.

```
class ExampleTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # Set up data for the whole TestCase
        self.user = User.objects.create_superuser('Testuser','test@user.com','1234')

    def test_user(self):
        # access the user with self.user
        ...
```

In earlier versions of Django which don't have `setUpTestData`, you can create the user in the [`setUp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) method.

```
class ExampleTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_superuser('Testuser','test@user.com','1234')
```

Comment: Altough meanwhile I found this out for myself and just wanted to add it as a answer, thank you Alasdair, you answered my question yesterday and today again. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up the database in your [`DATABASES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASES) settings.

> Django sets up a [test database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) corresponding to every database that is
>   defined in the `DATABASES` definition in your settings file.
>
> By default the test databases get their names by prepending `test_` to
>   the value of the `NAME` settings for the databases defined in `DATABASES`.

If you want to use a different database name, specify `NAME` in the `TEST` dictionary for any given database in `DATABASES`.

An example test database configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'TEST': { # test database settings
            'NAME': 'mytestdatabase', # test database name
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: forgot to add that I run my tests with

python manage.py test

it is setting a testdatabase there for itself, so I don't have to define a Database in my settings, or do I?
Will update the question.

Comment: Yes, you need to define a database in your `DATABASES` settings.

Comment: I updated the question a second time, please have a look.

Comment: In case of default database with the name `pim_testdatabase`, Django will automatically create a test database of name `test_` + `pim_testdatabase` ie. `test_pim_testdatabase`. Check that the database settings defined in `DEFAULT` are correct and connection is being established. Also, make sure that the user defined has the permissions to create the test database.

Comment: I think you are focusing on the wrong thing, or I am just not able to understand what you mean.
As I wrote in my question, the test starts running without any problem and spins up the server and the database as long as the line with `create_superuser` isn't there. My problem, I think, is with the create_superuser

Comment: Seems like i misunderstood your question. Try putting the objects creation code into `setUp()` as @Alasdair mentioned. Seems like that might be the culprit.

Comment: Yes, that totally solved my problem, and thank you for your effort.